# Can I clone my current win 10 OS partition and install it on a 2nd partition for a dual boot system?

Tags: dualboot

I just got a new computer and have finished setting up win 10 to my preferences and installed various apps.

What I'd like to do now is shrink the partition and create a 2nd partition. I would like to clone my current OS and copy this to the new partition and end up with a dual boot with two instances of win 10. Would this work?

What is the best way of modifying the boot master record to make this work?

Comment: What you propose isn’t allowed by the EULA for Windows

Comment: That's not what I asked but thanks

Comment: Thinking about it  this is likely very difficult since the drive letter would change. Maybe there are programs that can automatically change every c:\ designated path to d:\ but it seems like a process fraught with possible pitfalls.